# Failing to drag and drop an element from within a tab group onto another tab

Tags: angular, drag-and-drop

I'm using a tab group to present a bunch of data.  Each tab contains a collection of elements that are draggable.  I'm trying to allow a drop onto an inactive tab label, and am having difficulties.  Though the labels have been given the 'droppable' attribute, they don't seem to register as a droppable zone.

```
<mat-tab-group style="height:600px;">
    <mat-tab *ngFor="let tech of selectedTerritory?.Technicians">
      <ng-template mat-tab-label droppable
        [dropScope]="isDropAllowed"
        [dragOverClass]="'drag-target-border'"
        (onDrop)="onServiceCallForwarded($event, tech.Id)">
          {{tech.Name}}
      </ng-template>
...
</mat-tab-group>
```

Is this simply not possible?  If it is possible, what am I missing?

Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Aha!  I sorted it out.
The I needed to add a div inside the ng-template that contains the droppable attribute.

Comment: Could you post a code of the solution? Thanks.

Comment: this post is four years old, and I don't even know what project I was working on, but the answer I gave seems pretty clear.  Taking the code sample from the question, replace {{tech.name}} with <div>{{tech.name}}</div> and that should make the droppable work.